# Jquery Ajax requesting different page but submits to same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I was working on comment system and unfortunately I ran into the following issue: **When I call Ajax to send POST data to `verify.php` page, its sending the data to same page I am calling it from, called `page.php`**. And also, its returning the following error in console along with the complete html code of the current page:

> jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: a.replace is not a function

The following is my jquery:

```
  var logged=<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["user"])){echo "true";}else{echo "false";}?>;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".comments_submit").click(function(){
            if(logged){
                var pid=this.id.split("_")[2];
                var comment=$("#comments_box_"+pid).val();
                if(comment.length>4){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"verify.php",
                        type:"POST",
                        data:{"add_comment":true,"pid":pid,"comment":comment},
                        success:function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            try{
                                var resp=JSON.parse(response);
                                if(resp.code=="ADD_COMMENT_SUC"){
                                    $("#comments").prepend($(resp.data).fadeIn('slow'));
                                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#comments").offset().top-60}, 500);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    toastr.remove()
                                    toastr.error("Server Error! Please Try Again!");
                                }
                            }
                            catch(err){
                                toastr.remove()
                                toastr.error(err);
                            }
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            toastr.remove()
                            toastr.error("Client Error! Please Try Again!");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#comments_box_"+pid).focus();
                    toastr.remove()
                    toastr.error("Please Enter Some Text To Comment!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                swal("Not Logged In!", "Please login to comment!", "warning");
            }
        });
    });
```

**Update**:

My PHP for comment system:

```
<div class="panel" id="comments_panel">
            <div class="panel-body">

              <div class="comments margin-horizontal-20">
                <h3>Comments</h3>
                <div id="comments">
                <?php
                $sql="SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `pid`='$pid' ORDER BY `cid` DESC";
                $result=$conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows>0)
                {
                    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<div class="comment media" id="comment_'.$row["cid"].'">
                                  <div class="media-left">
                                    <a class="avatar avatar-lg" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                      <img src="'.get_gravatar(uid2email($row["uid"])).'" alt="'.uid2username($row["uid"]).'">
                                    </a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="media-body">
                                    <div class="comment-body">
                                      <a class="comment-author" href="javascript:void(0)">'.uid2username($row["uid"]).'</a>
                                      <div class="comment-meta">
                                        <span class="date">'.timeago($row["time"]).'</span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="comment-content">
                                        <p>'.$row["comment"].'</p>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="comment-actions">
                                        '.count_likes($row["cid"]).' <i class="icon md-thumb-up comments_like ';if(check_like($row["cid"])){echo 'comments_like_active';} echo '" id="comment_like_'.$row["cid"].'"></i>
                                        '.count_dislikes($row["cid"]).' <i class="icon md-thumb-down comments_dislike ';if(check_dislike($row["cid"])){echo 'comments_dislike_active';} echo '" id="comment_dislike_'.$row["cid"].'"></i>
                                        '.count_sub_comments($row["cid"]).' <i class="icon md-comments comments_comments"></i>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="comments">';
                        $sql2="SELECT * FROM `sub_comments` WHERE `cid`='$row[cid]'";
                        $result2=$conn->query($sql2);
                        if($result2->num_rows>0){
                            while($row2=$result2->fetch_assoc()){
                                echo '<div class="comment media">
                                        <div class="media-left">
                                          <a class="avatar avatar-lg" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                            <img src="'.get_gravatar(uid2email($row2["uid"])).'" alt="'.uid2username($row2["uid"]).'">
                                          </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="comment-body media-body">
                                          <a class="comment-author" href="javascript:void(0)">'.uid2username($row2["uid"]).'</a>
                                          <div class="comment-meta">
                                            <span class="date">'.timeago($row2["time"]).'</span>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="comment-content">
                                            <p>'.$row2["sub_comment"].'</p>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="comment-actions">
                                            '.count_sub_likes($row2["scid"]).' <i class="icon md-thumb-up sub_comments_like ';if(check_sub_like($row2["scid"])){echo 'sub_comments_like_active';} echo '" id="sub_comment_like_'.$row2["scid"].'"></i>
                                            '.count_sub_dislikes($row2["scid"]).' <i class="icon md-thumb-down sub_comments_dislike ';if(check_sub_dislike($row2["scid"])){echo 'sub_comments_dislike_active';} echo '" id="sub_comment_dislike_'.$row2["scid"].'"></i>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                        echo '<div class="form-group form-material floating">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="sub_comments_box_'.$row["cid"].'"></textarea>
                                        <label class="floating-label" for="sub_comments_box_'.$row["cid"].'">Leave A Reply</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                      <button class="btn btn-default sub_comments_submit" type="button" id="sub_comments_submit_'.$row["cid"].'"><i class="md-comment-edit"></i></button>
                                    </span></div></div></div></div></div>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Be the first to comment!";
                }
                ?>
                <div class="form-group form-material floating">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="form-control-wrap">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comments_box_<?php echo $pid;?>" rows="3"></textarea>
                            <label class="floating-label" for="comments_box_<?php echo $pid;?>">Add A Comment</label>
                        </div>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default comments_submit" type="button" id="comments_submit_<?php echo $pid;?>"><i class="md-comment-edit"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Panel Comments -->
```

Comment: Sorry for adding `php` and `html` tags but I wanted more people to help me resolve my issue.

Comment: The "comment_submit" element is probably a button that needs to be explicitly marked as `type="button"` to prevent the surrounding `<form>` from being submitted.

Comment: @Pointy I usually dont use forms, so there is no form tag in my entire page

Comment: OK, well without seeing the HTML it's hard to say what the problem is. You can look at the HTTP transactions in the browser console or network tab to see what's actually happening.

Comment: @Pointy I have updated with my PHP code

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Nope, I used find, but i couldn't find "replace" word in my entire php or js files.

Comment: The `.replace()` error is coming from inside jQuery.

Comment: `$("#comments").prepend($(resp.data).fadeIn('slow'));` doesn't look right to me. You're trying to prepend the return value from the fadeIn method. I doubt it returns anything at all. Try `$("#comments").prepend(resp.data).fadeIn('slow');` (I haven't tested). That should animate the prepend action with a fade, which I think is what was intended.

Comment: Sorry for Delay,@Pointy Nothing is wrong with Jquery, since there is no error, if i remove comment system related javascript.

Comment: @ADyson Nope, the error still remains, anyways the animation effect code was taken from stackoverflow answers itself and it works properly when tested individually.